# Как сравнить два списка и выдать результат в виде третьего списка?

Tags: c#, list, сравнение, diff

Есть некий объект (назовём его Line) описывающий некие данные, обязательное поле у которого ID (*Сразу сообщу, что ID - не уникальный и две структуры в списке могут иметь одинаковый ID*), и другие поля могут отличаться, но структуры считаются похожими (не совпадающими), если у них одинаковый ID.

Есть два списка:

```
var List1 = new List<Line>();
var List2 = new List<Line>();
```

Элементы в этом списке могут повторяться, а ID могут идти не последовательно.
Мне нужно сравнить эти два списка по полям ID и сформировать результирующий список следующей структуры:

```
Line first;
Line second;
```

где в полях first и second лежат элементы из первого и второго списка соответственно, в случае совпадения ID этих записей, а если элемент присутствует в первом списке, но отсутствует во втором (и наоборот), отсутствующее поле содержало бы null.

Например.
Line содержит структуру:

```
int ID;
int value;
```

Списки инициировали следующими данными:

```
List1 = {5, 5}, {5, 1}, {7, 7}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {2, 2}, {9, 9}, {1, 1}, {1, 5};
List2 = {5, 5}, {7, 7}, {5, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 3};
```

На выходе нужно получить следующую структуру данных:

```
ListRet = {
    {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}, {{5, 1}, null}, {{7, 7}, {7, 7}}, {null, {5, 1}}, 
    {{3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {null, {4, 4}}, {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}, {{6, 6}, {6, 6}}, 
    {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}, {{9, 9}, null}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 5}, {1, 3}}
};
```

Последовательность элементов важна

Подскажите, как можно реализовать подобный алгоритм? А если приведёте кусок кода на C#, моя благодарность не будет иметь границ.

Comment: Здесь не решают задач, а помогают в их решении. Покажите Ваши попытки решить задачу.

Comment: Пример ожидаемого результата не соответствует условию задачи. Любо я не понял условие.

Comment: Не совсем понял по примеру, что вы хотите в итоге получить. Не могли бы вы чуть подробнее расписать этот момент? Так же, если расскажите, зачем вам это, возможно, сможем подобрать иную реализацию, которая будет проще

Comment: Можете почитать https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.2.php или вот https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.4.php. Может это сможет помочь вам решить проблему

Comment: Rustam, а я и не прошу сделать всё за меня, я только прошу поделиться алгоритмом, если кто его знает. Если кто не знает, знает, но не хочет рассказать, не знает, но хочет показать, что, типа, знает, претензий к ним нет и быть не может! Я понимаю, что нужно проглядывать сначала первый список сравнивать со вторым, а потом второй с первым, но у меня проблема в том, как связать эти два результата.

Comment: Aepot, Знаете утилиту diff? Она сравнивает два текста построчно и выдаёт текстовый файл в котором, если строка есть в первом файле и её нет во втором, эта строка начинается с "минуса". Если строка есть во втором файле, но её нет в первом, то в выходном файле строка начинается с "плюса". Если строка присутствует и там, и там, то она просто выводится в выходной файл. Вот, что-то подобное мне и нужно реализовать.

Comment: Frehzy, у меня есть, скажем, плей-лист, который был сформирован одним человеком, Второй человек его отредактировал: удалил какие-то файлы, а какие-то файлы добавил. Мне нужно увидеть какие файлы были добавлены вторым человеком, а какие удалены им же. Проблема в том, что в плей-листе могут присутствовать одни и те же файлы по нескольку раз, значит просто методы except и interscept тут не помогут. Сортировать списки по алфавиту и группировать, чтобы узнать количество того или иного файла, тоже нельзя, так как важен порядок следования файлов.